# AlertDialog OnCLickListener needs pressing back button to be active

Tags: android

I've been trying to make it work for hours, but I can't find any suitable solution.

Here's the thing: I create an AlertDialog with 2 buttons, and set one OnClickListener on each of them.

The problem is that I have to press the back button to be able to "click" on one of the alert's buttons.

```
Context myActivity = getContext();
OnClickListener posClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        Log.d("AlertBuilder", "positive button");
        dialog.cancel();
        dialog.dismiss();

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.facebook.katana"));
        getContext().startActivity(intent);
    }
};
OnClickListener negClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        Log.d("AlertBuilder", "negative button");
        dialog.cancel();
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
};

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(myActivity);
builder.setMessage("Impossible de lancer l'application Facebook.\r\nVeuillez vérifier que vous avez installé et mis à jour l'application Facebook.")
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setNegativeButton("Retour", negClickListener)
        .setPositiveButton("Télécharger", posClickListener);
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();

alert.dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)); // I tried this to simulate the back button action, but it doesn't work
```

Do you see anything bad in here?

/* =============  EDIT  ============= */

Ok, I think I've figured out what's going on.

In fact I try t create this dialog within a FbDialog, which extends the Dialog Class.

Maybe Android doesn't like Inception...

Any idea of how to sort this out?

Answer (score 1):

Use simple inner class and check if it works...in "this" pass ur activity context..

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this); 
dialog.setMessage(message);   
dialog.setPositiveButton("TeleCharger", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
{       
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
    {  
        //put positive code here
    }   
});    
dialog.setNegativeButton("Retour", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
{        
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
    {
        //put negative code here
    }     
});    
dialog.create().show();
```

Comment: In fact this was the first code I tried, but didn't work (it did the same but I didn't think about pressing the back button).

So I tried taking out the listeners, just in case...

Comment: I tried your code, _just in case_, but the result is exactly the same: I still have to press the Back _"button"_...

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
        showDialog(getApplicationContext());

    return true;
    // use this instead if you want to preserve onKeyDown() behavior
    // return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
public void showDialog(Context mContext) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
    builder.setMessage("Impossible de lancer l'application Facebook.\r\nVeuillez vérifier que vous avez installé et mis à jour l'application Facebook.")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setNegativeButton("Retour", negClickListener)
                .setPositiveButton("Télécharger", posClickListener);
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

Comment: I think this is supposed to show a dialog when I press the back button, isn't it?

The problem is that I show the dialog when I get an error in my Phonegap plugin. But I have to press the back button to be able to click on the AlertDialog's buttons.
Without it, the OnClick event isn't fired...

Answer (score 0):

See if you want to cancel or dismiss the dialog(back press) you can make dialog as a cancleable true. 
e.g :

```
// it will not allow to cancel on back press
dlgAlert.setCancelable(false);
```

Comment: I tried false and true, but it does the same: I have to press back button at least once to be able to do something (press "back" again to dismiss or press a button)

That behaviour is kinda weird...